# Symfony2 JMSSerializer performance issue

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using JMSserializer over jsonrpc with symfony2. One of my request return more than 980 results (with references). This request only take 210ms to be executed, which is pretty fine, but the serialization take more than 30 seconds with a response weight of 35Mb. Any idea how to improve that ?

**EDIT** : I need all datas in the response, so no exclude or maxDepth policy required.

Answer (score 0):

All interfaces to the relationships and collections of the entity probably are serialized. That is the most common explanation of this. You should not try to serialize all those and make sure you only configure the primitive and scalar types to be serialized.